# Align svg text inline with d3.js legend

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I'm trying to use [Susie Lu's legend plugin](http://d3-legend.susielu.com/).

Here is a plnk of work so far;

http://plnkr.co/edit/wrOWPYu4PAqwr8f5OOjw?p=preview

Image below is what I would like to achieve (just layout, content/colour doesn't matter)

[image]

I've tried the standard `float:left` + `display: inline` on the classes attached to the text/rectangles but it didn't work for me. Maybe I was making a mistake. I'm not sure If I should be doing this inside the d3 script or in the css file anyway?

Hope this is a simple fix - any help is much appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those attributes (`float:left + display: inline`) only work on html elements, what the legend library here produces is svg

It's possible, but needs a little bit of work

http://plnkr.co/edit/YRFRWEtMFDmje06Mg5KY?p=preview

```
 var cells= d3.selectAll(".cell");
   var cellGap = legendLinear.shapeWidth()+(legendLinear.shapePadding()/4);

   cells.select("text")
      .attr ("transform", "translate("+cellGap+" 13)")
      .style ("text-anchor", "start")
   ; 

   var offset = 0;
   cells.each (function(d,i) {
      var d3sel = d3.select(this);
      var textWidth = d3sel.select("text").node().getComputedTextLength();
      var offsetInc = textWidth + legendLinear.shapeWidth() + legendLinear.shapePadding();
      d3sel.attr("transform", "translate("+offset+" 0)");
      offset += offsetInc;
   });
```

This firstly moves the text element for each legend 'cell' to the right of the colour swatch rather than below.

Then it moves the g elements that hold the label and swatch horizontally apart dependent on the width of the label (and the swatch and the declared padding) using `.getComputedTextLength()` and a running total for the offset.